# How to get longtable and bidi to work together?

Tags: longtable, bidi

I am typesetting a Hebrew document using bidi.  The material in the longtable environment still comes out LTR.  How do I make it work?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[no-sscript]{xltxtra} % loads fixltx2e, metalogo, xunicode, fontspec

\setmainfont{FreeSans}
\usepackage[rldocument]{bidi}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}llr}
\hline
מילה עברית&English Words&123, 456\\
\hline
English Text&מילים בעברית&12 3456\\
\hline
1234 56.&More English&עוד עברית\\
\hline
\end{longtable}

מילה עברית English Words 123, 456\\
English Text מילים בעברית 12 3456\\
1234 56. More English עוד עברית\
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: longtable doesn't seem to respect bidi]

Here are the lines from the output which describe the software and package versions I'm using:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-0.9998 (TeX Live 2012)
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, uk
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
bidi package (Support for bidirectional typesetting in plain TeX and LaTeX)
 Copyright © 2009–2012 Vafa Khalighi
 v11.149, 2012/01/01
```

Comment: ah. The maintainer of bidi contacted me a while back about that. It doesn't work I need to add some hooks to longtable but it isn't exactly clear where. (I thought it was clear but when I tried it it didn't work, I need to get back to it). Sorry about that. (If anyone else answers could they ping me either through the `@` mechanism here or via email)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle And Vafa is unfortunately no longer maintaining `bidi`.

Comment: @AlanMunn Oh it was only last month he mailed me?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  He sent mail announcing it to the XeTeX list on Aug 5.

Comment: Yes, I tried sending e-mail to Vafa, but I got back and 'e-mail address does not exist' from google.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle [This document](http://www.tug.org/texlive/devsrc/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bidi/longtable-xetex-bidi.def) is the first link on a google search for 'xetex bidi longtable,' but I don't know what to do with it.  Does that help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [developing final version of bidi package](https://github.com/persian-tex/bidi). It provides an experimental `bidi-longtable` package.

Comment: Thank you!  I've tried it with a few documents and it seems to work quite well.

Answer (score 2):

You could add the necessary commands to switch directions manually:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[no-sscript]{xltxtra} % loads fixltx2e, metalogo, xunicode, fontspec

\setmainfont{Arial Unicode MS}
\usepackage[rldocument]{bidi}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}llr}
\hline
מילה עברית&English Words&123, 456\\
\beginR מילה עברית\endR &English Words&123, 456\\
\RL{מילה עברית} &English Words&123, 456\\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I was afraid that would be the answer.  At least  `\usepackage{array} \newcolumntype{R}{>{\beginR}r<{\endR}}` seems to work.  Is there any difference here between the `\beginR` primitive and `\RL{}`?  Is there no way to get xetex to start the columns on the right side, aside from entering them in reverse order?